# How to override accessibility role in react-navigation

Tags: react-native, react-navigation-v6

I wanted to start updating my react-navigation dependency from version 5.X to version 6.x but I'm running into problems regarding an accessibility setting that is hardcoded in the codebase for their bottom tab bar.

In their `BottomTabBar.tsx` they have a view that looks like the following

```
<View accessibilityRole="tablist" style={styles.content}>
```

And this results in the error below

[image: This is the error I'm receiving]

It made me think it was a bug in the library but somehow I was not able to reproduce the same issue in a expo snack. Changing the value for something else like "button" solves the issue but I don't like to mess around in the node_modules. Another solution would be to override the tab bar and write a custom implementation (I've tried this when worrying not to much about styling) but this kind of is a big overhead for something that appears to be simple

Comment: i have same issue did you find any solution..

Comment: Unfortunately haven’t found a proper solution yet. For the moment I did something I’m not particularly proud of… since it’s still a feature branch in active development I simply hardcoded it to another value to be able to continue working on the feature. Before merging back I need to find something more permanent

Comment: yea bro.. I have same issue.. Please let us know if you find any solution...

Comment: @BerkKanburlar I updated my dependencies and the issue appears to be solved for me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A new update to the library has fixed the issue for me, at the time of writing the answer the combination of packages below is what appears to work for me

```
"@react-navigation/bottom-tabs": "^6.2.0",
"@react-navigation/native": "^6.0.8",
"@react-navigation/stack": "^6.1.1",
```

Comment: i fixed it by changing source code of react navigation :P